# In Google Analytics, how can I find top 5 days sorted by number of visitors?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there an easy way of finding the 5 most visited days?

I want a report on this format:

```
Date         Visitors
dd-mm-yyyy   320
dd-mm-yyyy   301
dd-mm-yyyy   256
dd-mm-yyyy    99
```

Comment: are you using the API or the website?

Comment: I am using the website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about usage of the Google Analytics website and is not programing related question probably better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since apparently only programming questions are allowed, here is the needed API call to retrieve the data programmatically:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=gaXXX&start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3Adate&sort=-ga%3Ausers&max-results=5
```

Demo can be seen in the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3Adate&sort=-ga%3Ausers&max-results=5)